# iPad App KeyBoard hide causing design issue

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I have a login page with Username text input and Password input.
There is a radio button for "remember me" functionality.

[image: This is what the normal login page looks like]

```css
.login_bg
{
 background:url(../images/bg_rest.jpg) no-repeat center;
 background-size:cover;
}

.rel_positioning
{
 position:relative;
}

.all_container
{
 width:1024px;
 height:770px;
 margin:0 auto;
 position:fixed;

}
```

```html
    <div data-role="page" id="login">
        <div class="all_container login_bg rel_positioning">
        <div class="netInfo" id="connectDetails"></div>
            <div class="fields_conatiner">
                <div class="login_txtbox">
                    <form id="loginFields">
                        <input class="left_txtbox" data-role="none" id="username" value="" name="text-6" placeholder="Username" type="text">
                        <input class="right_txtbox" data-role="none" id="password" name="text-6" placeholder="Password" type="password" value="" 
                        onkeypress="loginUser(this);">
                        <div class="chkbox">
                            <input data-role="none" id="autoLoginCk" type="checkbox" />
                            <label class="autoLogin_lbl" for="autoLoginCk"></label><span>Keep me logged in</span>
                        </div>
                        <input data-role="none" onclick="userSignInValidator();" type="button" value="Login">
                        <div class="btm_login">
                            <a data-form="ui-link-a" onclick="showForgotPasswordView();">Forget Login Details</a>
                            <a data-form="ui-link-a" onclick="showRegistrationView();">Register New Account</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

After entering credentials if i touch the radio button, the keyboard goes down and half the screen becomes white. That is, the UI is brought down when the keyboard disappears and a white background appears below the UI i designed.

[image: once the keyboard is gone after entering and touching remember me]

Does anybody know why this happens, and where is the issue?

Comment: "a picture is worth a thousand words".

Comment: Also: Provide your code.

Comment: It has to be with the css, but not able to identify the fix needed